# Differentiation of multiple domain hosted on same server

Tags: networking, dns, server

Suppose that a server (which has ip address 123.123.123.123) is hosting 4 domains named abc.xyz, abc.abc, xyz.abc, xyz.xyz. If I do ping any of the websites I will get ip address 123.123.123.123 (since the dns name of the domains are same ip address). But when someone requests from browser to fetch contents from abc.xyz , in the data packet browser sends only the ip address. So how the server side differentiates which of the domain is requested by the user?

Comment: Look at in /etc/hosts  or your or  your OS hosts file .. in there it that configuration

Comment: I have windows pc.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Answer (score 0):

As you OS is Windows  Look at  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  in there will contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names that browser resolve

```
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```